# Unexpected behaviour of append

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

```
l="??"
ans=[]
g=list(l)
def allcombination(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]=='?':
            x[i]='A'
            allcombination((x))
            ans.append(list(x))           #the problem is in this line, changing list(x) to x gives a different answer.
            x[i]='B'
            allcombination((x))
            ans.append(list(x))           #the problem is in this line, changing list(x) to x gives a different answer
            return
allcombination(g)
print(ans)
```

> The output is:
> [['A', 'A'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'B']]

```
l="??"
ans=[]
g=list(l)
def allcombination(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]=='?':
            x[i]='A'
            allcombination((x))         #the problem is in this line
            ans.append((x))
            x[i]='B'
            allcombination((x))         #the problem is in this line
            ans.append((x))
            return
allcombination(g)
print(ans)
```

> The output is:
> [['B', 'B'], ['B', 'B'], ['B', 'B'], ['B', 'B']]

Ignore what the code is about, why the difference in output? Please give solution and the detailed reason. Incase you are curious, the below code gives the desired output:

```
l="??"
ans=[]
g=list(l)
def allcombination(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]=='?':
            x[i]='A'
            allcombination(list(x))
            x[i]='B'
            allcombination(list(x))
            return
    ans.append(list(x))        #ans.append((x)) will NOT give the right answer, Idk why.
allcombination(g)
print(ans)
```

> The output is:
> [['A', 'A'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'A'], ['B', 'B']]

The comments in the codes above point out the problem.
How does it matter if I use, list(x) or x, I have even printed the type(x), it is of the type list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending with `ans.append(x)` does the add the `x` list, that one instance, then if you modify it, you'll see in there too, as it points to it

A simple example to show that

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [a]
print(b)  # [[1, 2, 3]]

a[0] = 6
print(b)  # [[6, 2, 3]]
```

Whereas `ans.append(list(x))` does **copy** `x`, then you have saved in `ans` a list with the values of `x`, not not `x` **itself**, that allows you do continue using `x`